# unable to build cuda 7.0 samples on linux with clang

Tags: linux, cuda, clang

I'm trying to build cuda samples version 7.0 on linux (redhat 7) using clang. Cuda 5.5, 6.0, 6.5 samples can be successfully built with clang, but when i'm trying to build 7.0 samples - the following error appears:

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin /usr/local/bin/clang++ -I../../common/inc -m64 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -o simplePrintf.o -c simplePrintf.cu 
nvcc fatal : Host compiler targets unsupported OS. 
make: *** [simplePrintf.o] Error 1
```

My params from makefile:

```
HOST_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/clang++
TARGET_OS=linux
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Outside my area of expertise, but I think CUDA supports clang on Mac OS X only, not on Linux. The error message you get appears to jibe with that. NVIDIA documents supported OS platforms and compilers in the "Getting Started" guides for each major OS platform supported by CUDA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clang isn't a supported compiler on linux for CUDA.

You can discover the supported configurations [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#system-requirements)

Comment: with CUDA 7.5RC, clang (3.5, and 3.6) is now a supported host compiler on linux.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, `clang` is not supported. In my case, changing it to `usr/bin/g++` did the trick.